# Changing keyboard command for retrieving mouse cursor coordinates

Tags: keyboard, macos, mouse, shortcut

From what I've understood, <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> is the way one currently gets Mouse Cursor Coordinates in macOS.

I use this combination for something else. Is there a way to change the keyboard command for retrieving the Mouse Cursor Coordinates? I tried looking in *Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts*, but didn't find anything.

Perhaps then, the keyboard command could be edited with something like Karabiner?

If the keyboard shortcut is not editable, is there a good and simple stand-alone tool for retrieving coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That key combination is for producing a picture from a section of the screen selected by the mouse and so that key combination is already fixed. It just conveniently shows the co-ordinates when selecting.

Unless it is possible to edit in the kernel or somewhere...

Comment: The implication is in that case that one simply changes the keyboard shortcut for screenshotting a part of the screen, which is available at *Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screen shots*.

Comment: It may be editable there - however I use that shortcut for what it is set to already so don't want to edit mine...